# Have Jenkins automatically configure IIS application for new GIT branches on deploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up my Jenkins build job as a multi-branch pipeline project with a `Jenkinsfile`.  It automatically scans git for branches to build and deploys the result to subdirectories of a IIS virtual path.  This works great for front-end code.

However, for .Net projects it is necessary to configure each directory as an "application" in IIS.

Is there a way to make my build script automatically create "IIS applications" and set the application pool for any newly discovered branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your Jenkinsfile:

```
stage("Deploy web application") {
  steps {
  ...
  virtualPath = '/myapp/' + env.BRANCH_NAME
  physicalPath = 'C:\myapp\\'+env.BRANCH_NAME
  addIisApplication('appName', 'appPoolName', virtualPath, physicalPath)
  }
}

def addIisApplication(appName, appPoolName, virtualPath, physicalPath) {
  iisAppCmd("add app /site.name:" + appName + " /path:" + virtualPath +" /physicalpath:"+physicalPath)
  iisAppCmd("set app "+appName + virtualPath+" /applicationpool:" + appPoolName)
}

def iisAppCmd(args) {
  bat 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe ' + args + " & exit 0" // ignore already exists error
}
```

If you need to create the IIS application on a different server, invoke `appcmd.exe` via [SysInternals PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Now, any time you create a new feature branch and push it, Jenkins can build and deploy it to your IIS server.